# Code returns empty dataframe without index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to make a dataframe with Historical data of daily No. of stock Advancing and declining with their respective volumes of Nifty 50 index.
Being new to python I am having trouble handling pandas dataframe and conditions.

Below is the code that I wrote, but it has a lot of issues:

1. df.index = data.index error:ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 248 elements
2. if I comment out the above line where I set the index of the empty dataframe, the code runs and gives an empty Dataframe at the end.

   ```
   #setting default dates
   end_date = date.today()
   start_date = end_date - timedelta(365)

   #Deriving the names of 50 stocks in Nifty 50 Index
   nifty_50 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIFTY_50')

   nifty50_symbols = nifty_50[1][1]

   df = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'Advances','Declines','Adv_Volume','Dec_Volume'})


   for x in nifty50_symbols:
       data = nsepy.get_history(symbol = x, start=start_date, end=end_date)
       sclose = data['Close']
       sopen = data['Open']
       svol = data['Volume']


    ##    df.index = data.index

    ##   for i in df.index: --- since df.index was commented out it's value was nill
       for i in data.index:
           if sclose > sopen:
               df['Advances'] = df['Advances'] + 1
               df['Adv_Volume'] = df['Adv_Volume'] + svol

           elif sopen > sclose:
               df['Declines'] = df['Declines'] + 1
               df['Dec_Volume'] = df['Dec_Volume'] + svol


   print(df.tail())
   ```

Output :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Dec_Volume, Declines, Advances, Adv_Volume]
Index: []
```

EDIT: Found the reason why the code was giving an empty dataframe, because df.index was nill, so the if statement was never triggered.When I changed that part into data.index if statement was triggered. But Now I do not know how do I use the IF statements, since it is giving the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

EDIT2: Updated Code with the help of Akshay Nevrekar: Still getting an empty dataframe at the end. Also I have to set index of DF as the dates in data.index, so that I can later relate the Advances/declines to their respective dates.

```
#setting default dates
end_date = date.today()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(365)

#Deriving the names of 50 stocks in Nifty 50 Index
nifty_50 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIFTY_50')

nifty50_symbols = nifty_50[1][1]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'Advances','Declines','Adv_Volume','Dec_Volume'})


for x in nifty50_symbols:
    data = ns.get_history(symbol = x, start=start_date, end=end_date)
##    sclose = data['Close']
##    sopen = data['Open']
##    svol = data['Volume']

##    df.index = data.index

    for i in data.index:
        sclose=data.loc[i]['Close']
        sopen=data.loc[i]['Open']
        svol = data.loc[i]['Volume']

        if sclose > sopen :
            df['Advances'] = df['Advances'] + 1
            df['Adv_Volume'] = df['Adv_Volume'] + svol

        elif sopen > sclose :
            df['Declines'] = df['Declines'] + 1
            df['Dec_Volume'] = df['Dec_Volume'] + svol



print(df
```

)

Comment: add implementation of `ns.get_history()` in your code.

Comment: sorry I forgot to fix that ns here is nsepy.. I imported it as ns, I will edit and fix it.

Comment: can you edit the code with your latest attempt?

Comment: yes I already did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an empty dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'Advances','Declines','Adv_Volume','Dec_Volume'})
```

so `df.index` will be empty and

```
 for i in df.index:
    if sclose > sopen:
        df['Advances'] = df['Advances'] + 1
        df['Adv_Volume'] = df['Adv_Volume'] + svol

    elif sopen > sclose:
        df['Declines'] = df['Declines'] + 1
        df['Dec_Volume'] = df['Dec_Volume'] + svol
```

you above **for loop** will never run. That's why you are getting an empty dataframe.

**Edit** : After your edit I would suggest you declare sclose and sopen variables in for loop. You are assigning entire column to variable instead of single value.

```
for i in data.index:
    sclose=data.iloc[i]['Close']
    sopen=data.iloc[i]['Open']
    svol=data.iloc[i]['Volume']

    if sclose > sopen:
       df.loc[i]['Advances'] = df.loc[i]['Advances'] + 1
       df.loc[i]['Adv_Volume'] = df.loc[i]['Adv_Volume'] + svol
    elif sopen > sclose:
       df.loc[i]['Declines'] = df.loc[i]['Declines'] + 1
       df.loc[i]['Dec_Volume'] = df.loc[i]['Dec_Volume'] + svol
```

Comment: Thank you, do I need to make a new question for the remaining error(s)?
Since this answer satisfies the Title but I am still having issue with getting the desired output.

Comment: .iloc of pandas gave me this error - TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [2017-02-06] of <class 'datetime.date'>

Comment: use `loc` instead of `iloc` then. I thought you are having integers as an index.

Comment: Well the code ran but still getting empty dataframe when I print df at the end, also I still do not know how to set the index of DF same as  data.index, so I can relate the Advances/Declines data with Date.

Comment: use  `loc` again where you are assigning the values. `df.loc[i][column]= ` .

Comment: I got the error KeyError: 'the label [2017-02-06] is not in the [index]', because the index of the dataframe df is empty. I am unable to assign the df inside the loop because that will reset the dataframe's data everytime. defining it outside means I do not have the data to fill for it's index. Hence I tried filling the index inside the loop with df.index = data.index but that also returned an error

Comment: I think the formula you got here is wrong. `df.loc[i]['Advances'] = df.loc[i]['Advances'] + 1`   You are trying to add 1 to the value even before initializing it.